# How to send Active Directory Group SID in SAML response from OKTA?

Tags: response, saml, okta

**Is it possible to send AD Group SID in SAML response?** If yes, how can that be achieved so that we can process that SID value in our SP?

However we were able to send AD User SID in SAML response after doing profile mapping of appuser.objectSid to user.manager(as we didn't find user.objectSid) and adding it to attribute statements.

[image]

**Is there any other/better way to obtain AD User SID in SAML response or above is the only way to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

So - you have 2 questions here:

1)  Group SID.  Okta does have Group SID but it isn't exposed as part of SAML config.  You can send name(s) of groups that the user is a member of as part of the group attribute statement configurable in the SAML configuration of the app wizard (https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/Using-the-App-Integration-Wizard#Config_SAMLSettings)

2)  For user SID, it's a 2 part setup.  First, you want to add a custom attribute to the Okta user profile.  That will allow you to then map the appuser.objectSid from AD to this custom attribute - rather than overloading some existing okta attribute that doesn't make sense.  THen in the app wizard SAML config, you can add a new attribute to your SAML assertion and associate that with the newly added custom attribute.

Both group/user attribute statement config is done here (app wizard SAML config screenshot)

[image: Okta App Wizard SAML screenshot]

Hope this helps.